# Wildcard Domain on Juniper Netscreen

Tags: domain, wildcard, juniper, netscreen

On a Juniper Netscreen firewall, is there a character that can be used as a wildcard with a domain?  For example, under the Objects -> Addresses section, if I want to create a new object similar to *.mydomain.net, how would I accomplish this?

*.mydomain.net and simply mydomain.net do not have the desired effect.

Answer (score 1):

Wildcards don't work. Sorry.